# How execute service 20 minute after on receive boot?

Tags: java, android, handler

i want execute service 20 minute after on receive boot completed , 
the handler postdelayed stop after sleep screen .
I want a timer that works even when the screen sleep

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {


        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Boot.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, BootService.class);
                context.startService(startServiceIntent);


            }
        },1200000);


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` for the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast, and set an alarm via the `AlarmManager` to trigger another broadcast and that receiver should start your `Service`.

Comment: I can offer you something close via an article I wrote a while back on using alarms.  It includes a working example of setting an alarm after boot completed.  You'll just need to add in your own custom time: http://po.st/7UpipA